# Green’s function of poisson’s equation in general dimensions

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, greens-function, poissons-equation, regularization

Green’s function of the Helmholtz equation, in the general dimension D, can be calculated as follows:
\begin{align}
G(\mathbf{r})&=\int \frac{d^D{k}}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{e^{-i \mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}}{\mathbf{k}^2+m^2}\\
&=\int \frac{d^D{k}}{(2\pi)^D} e^{-i \mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}} \int_0^\infty dt\ e^{-t(\mathbf{k}^2+m^2)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\Big(\frac{m}{2\pi r} \Big)^{\frac{D}{2}-1} K_{\frac{D}{2}-1}(mr).
\end{align}
I’m looking for the same representation about Poisson’s equation, but it is difficult because the similar integral is divergent. In fact,
\begin{align}
G(\mathbf{r})&=\int \frac{d^D{k}}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{e^{-i \mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}}}{\mathbf{k}^2}\\
&=\int \frac{d^D{k}}{(2\pi)^D} e^{-i \mathbf{k}\mathbf{r}} \int_0^\infty dt\ e^{-t\mathbf{k}^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{\frac{D}{2}}}\int_0^\infty dt \frac{1}{t^{\frac{D}{2}}} e^{-\frac{r^2}{4t}}\\
\end{align}
is divergent especially when D=1 or 2. Does anybody know about the closed expression or treatment of this divergent integral which can be used even in one or two dimension? Of course, I know the other way to calculate Green’s function in low dimensions. I want to know how to treat this integral. I guess this integral needs some regularization, but I don’t know.

Comment: When $D=1$ you simply have the Fourier transform of $1/k^2$ (which has many answers on this site). When $D=2$ you can perform one $k$ integral which yields a similar Fourier integral. When $D>2$ you already have a regularized integral from the Helmholtz Green's function; after using the [asymptotic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms) of $K_\nu$ for small arguments, the $m \to 0$ limit is harmless. This can also get you the correct logarithmic behavior when $D=2$

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653340/2451